# Load and prepend to body jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

When i try to multiple load files into the script, it doesnt prepend, it replace.

Here is my body part :

```
<body class="about-us Home-two Home-three">
<!-- jquery
============================================ -->
<script src="/assets/js/vendor/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<!-- bootstrap JS
============================================ -->
<script src="/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- wow JS
============================================ -->
<script src="/assets/js/wow.min.js"></script>
<!-- price-slider JS
============================================ -->
<script src="/assets/js/jquery-price-slider.js"></script>
<!-- meanmenu JS
============================================ -->
<script src="/assets/js/jquery.meanmenu.js"></script>
<!-- owl.carousel JS
============================================ -->
<script src="/assets/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<!-- scrollUp JS
============================================ -->
<script src="/assets/js/jquery.scrollUp.min.js"></script>
<!-- plugins JS
============================================ -->
<script src="/assets/js/plugins.js"></script>
<!-- Nivo slider js
============================================ -->
<script src="/assets/custom-slider/js/jquery.nivo.slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/custom-slider/home.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- main JS
============================================ -->
<script src="/assets/js/url.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        getPage(url('2'));
    });
</script>
</body>
```

I want to prepend header.php and banner.php into this

And i tried this code :

```
$(".about-us").load("/parts/header.php").prependTo("body");
$(".about-us").load("/parts/banner.php").prependTo("body");
```

But only header added. How can i multiple load scripts into body ?

Comment: `$(".about-us").clone().load("/parts/banner.php").prependTo("body");`

Comment: Are you trying to prepend result of `.load()` call to `body` or `.about-us` element?

Comment: Why... are you not just doing this server side to begin with? There is zero reason to do this only after the page gets to the client, just presenting your users with a shitty page that then takes another two network round trips just to build the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to prepend response of `.load()` to `.about-us` or `body`, substitute `$.get()` for `.load()`. `.load()` replaces existing content.

```
$.when($.get("/parts/header.php"), $.get("/parts/banner.php"))
.then(function(header, banner) {
  $.each([header.shift(), banner.shift()], function(index, content) {
    $(".about-us").prepend(content);
  });
});
```